# Numerical sort on custom field which includes letters

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do a sort in my WP_Query on a custom field. The custom field contains strings such as "E100", "E500" and "E123b". I would like to sort numerically on these values, i.e. sort on the custom field as if the characters weren't there.

My query looks like this:

```
$subpages = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type" => "page",
    "meta_key" => "[customFieldNameHere]",
    "orderby" => "meta_value_num",
    "order" => "ASC",
    "posts_per_page" => 5000
));
```

But it doesn't work. It does some sort of sort, but it's not numerical. Is it possible to strip all characters/letters from the field, and then do a numerical sort on the remaining values, or is there some other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the leading E from all strings. Doesn't really solve the original problem, with numerical sorting of strings, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort a string with letters as if it were all numbers. If you try you will get a alphanumerical sort-- more or less what you'd do if you were alphabetizing something but it makes numbers look odd because it matches up all the first characters, then the second, and so on making numbers look like:

- 1
- 10
- 101
- 2
- 20

I don't know of anything built into MySQL that will do what you want, nor does `WP_Query` have any such feature. The best solution I have is to pull your results unsorted, and sort them later. You want to pull unsorted so the database doesn't do extra work.

```
$subpages = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type" => "page",
    "meta_key" => "[customFieldNameHere]",
    "posts_per_page" => 5000
));

$sorted = array();
foreach ($subpages as $s) {
  $kname = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$s->customFieldNameHere]);
  $sorted[$kname] = $s;
}
// you may need
// ksort($sorted); 
var_dump($sorted);
```

One problem is going to be collisions. If you end up with two matching `$knames` you will clobber data, and frankly, that seems pretty likely if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Hmm... yes, that's not going to work. There will be values such as "E120a" and "E120b" stored in the custom fields.